# Tensorflow error : loaded runtime CuDNN library: 6021 (compatibility version 6000) but source was compiled with 5110 (compatibility version 5100)

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

Specifications :

```
Ubuntu 16.04
tensorflow 1.1.0
NVIDIA 850m 4GB
CUDA 8
CUDNN 6
```

I have created a soft link `ln -s libcudnn.so.6.* libcudnn.so.5` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013316/after-building-tensorflow-from-source-seeing-libcudart-so-and-libcudnn-errors). Else I was getting an error, `ImportError: libcudnn.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

This is a snapshot of `usr/local/cuda/lib64`
[image]
What should I do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install different cuDNN, if you use CUDA 8 you can try cuDNN 5.1 as described here: https://softwaremill.com/how-to-upgrade-aws-deep-learning-ami-to-tensorflow-1-1-0/ (look into cuDNN section only)

Comment: But I think that I have installed cuDNN 6 as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: From what i can see, you arę missing the ver 5, for cuda 8 you should get 5.1 and copy the files as described in the link

Comment: I have cuDNN 6 which is the latest version. Can't I just create a softlink to version 5.1?

Comment: Its not about getting the latest versions but about matching them to each other

Comment: Is there any official source which can tell which version of cuDNN I need for CUDA 8?

Comment: Im not aware of any, your err msg says it all imho though

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download. this mentions that cudnn 6 is also for cuda 8

Comment: Yes cuDNN 5.1 worked. Please edit your answer so that I may accept it

Comment: My answer says just that :)

Comment: Its not that straightforward, it does not work in your setup but it will possibly work for others

Answer (score 0):

It's no effect to create a soft link `ln -s libcudnn.so.6.* libcudnn.so.5`.

Just download cuDNN v5.1 from [cuDNN Download](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) and install it.

After that, it will create `libcudnn.so.5` and `libcudnn.so.5.1.10` automatically.

[image]