# Calling Tensforflow python script from cron doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When I call my Tensforflow python script from command line works fine as expected. 
But when I call it as a cronjob, I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know what's the problem, it is environment path related, more can be found here: [After building TensorFlow from source, seeing libcudart.so and libcudnn errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013316/after-building-tensorflow-from-source-seeing-libcudart-so-and-libcudnn-errors) but I am not sure how to resolve it so I could call a python script from a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/337631/crontab-execution-doesnt-have-the-same-environment-variables-as-executing-user), cronjob doesn't have the same environment as an executing user. The simplest solution is to provide one manually right in the cronjob:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc && python my_script.py
```