# Anaconda Tensorflow runtime issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run tensorflow with gpu support on my computer (NVIDIA 960 M) using anaconda and cuda but I keep running into this error. I have tried reinstalling cuda (normally and anaconda) multiple times.

```
>Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/aubin/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


>Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

>See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
>for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>above this error message when asking for help.
>>>>
```

Comment: Is it first time you face it ?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Tensorflow you have installed requires CUDA 9.0 (c.f. `libcublas.so.9.0` import attempt). You should check if you have it installed and properly setup.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013316/after-building-tensorflow-from-source-seeing-libcudart-so-and-libcudnn-errors) has several solutions to common CUDA- or cuDNN-related problems.