# Does installing both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu cause an error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I updated tensorflow to version 1.8 when tensorflow-gpu was already installed.

but this exception has occur.

> ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And I imported according to tensorflow's guidelines([42013316](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013316/after-building-tensorflow-from-source-seeing-libcudart-so-and-libcudnn-errors)).

But in my case it was not solved.

I would appreciate it if you could give a resolution.

environment:

ubuntu -16.04.01

gpu-nvidia 1080ti *4

tensorflow-1.8

tensorflow-gpu-1.8

python-2.7

Comment: have you installed CUDA and CUDNN?that shared file is for CUDA to be able to run on GPU

Comment: i installed cuda-9.0 , also installed cudnn.

Comment: is CUDA_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in your bash_profile file?

Comment: i export this lines:         export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH                            
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

Comment: did you make symbolic link from that point to /usr/local/cuda-9.0 to /usr/local/cuda? it seems you re point to cuda-9 in path and to cuda  in CUDA_HOME Path

Comment: yes, cuda-9.0's sybolic is in there.

Comment: not sure if it was not resolved by now...but it seems that cuda-9 wasn't supported in tensorflow few months ago.. you may consider to downgrade to 1.4 tensorflow and see how it goes ...here is a useful link about same problem...good luck https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14622\

Comment: Are there any issues about the simultaneous installation of tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu that you know?

Comment: I think you can't have both installed, the last installation will remove the previous one if you upgrade via pip, but you could have a native one and another in virtual environment

Comment: As long as they're not installed in the same python environment, they'll do just fine together on the same machine. Your error looks like you have the wrong version of CUDA/cuDNN installed

Comment: Should I lower the version of cuda? Or is there a version of cuda for tensorflow1.8?